Dll won't load problem migrating from VS2019 under Windows 10 to VS2022 under Windows VB
As above I'm migrating an app from Win10, VS2019 to Win11 VS2022.  In the Win11/2022 environment, I'm getting a "Unable to load dll...or one of it's dependencies. The specified module could not be found." Note that the parent app is a 32 bit (X86) vb app. The DLL is c++ (vs2013).
The DLL is fully qualified.  I ran dumpbin against the dll and the 6 dependencies are all in syswow64 as is the dll.
Here's the declaration and offending function call,
<DllImport("C:\windows\syswow64\MyFile.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>

Public Shared Function MyFile_open_device(ByVal index As Integer, ByRef errorCode As IntPtr) As Integer

End Function

In the mainline code MyFile_open_device is nested in a Try block that in turn throws the Try block's text explanation.
Other than questions you may have or suggestions as to how to diagnose (both of which are welcome), I'm wondering if anyone is aware of any changes between 10/11 or 2019/2022 that would cause this condition.
Here's the declaration and offending function call,
<DllImport("C:\windows\syswow64\MyFile.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>

Public Shared Function MyFile_open_device(ByVal index As Integer, ByRef errorCode As IntPtr) As Integer

End Function

I'm getting a "Unable to load dll...or one of it's dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

You should not be putting your DLLs anywhere in the Windows folder. It should be either in your own application's folder or in a folder on the Windows PATH. See the documentation for the Win32 function LoadLibrary() for the folders that are searched by default.

Hmm.  Not sure where you get the idea that dll's shouldn't be installed in windows folders.  Every case is different. In this case, the dll in question references several other dll's that are installed by MS and may or may not accessible based on the config of the machine.  Without tearing apart the target install platform, the best way is to install in the place with best access to all targets.  In this case the necessary MS dll's are all installed in Windows.  In Windows in particular, the "best case" is the one which best tolerates disruption.

I got the idea from MS, who says that everything within the Windows folder tree belongs to the OS, which is why non-admin users aren't allowed to write there. What planet have you been living on since UAC was introduced (actually, before that - when Win85 was released, so were Power Users and restricted rights)? If the DLL isn't part of the OS, it doesn't belong in the OS folders.

I've found most MS mandates in this regard to be useless at best and more usually detrimental when installing software in customer environments.  That's because customers are often wonderfully creative (irony) in the file system structures they deploy and down right giddy about their use of PATH(s).
Therefore, while the core exe of our app can be happy about any place, various components that are heavily MS dependent do not suffer file system creativity gladly.
We have been using this approach since 2010.  It is installed in mfg and gov't sites all over the world.  I never get support calls.

Nonsense. If you use a proper installer, the customer has nothing to do with the PATH or the location of files, and DLLs your app use that are in your own app's directory don't need to be added to the PATH anyway - that's the first place that is searched when a DLL is being loaded. Malware replacement of files in the system folders are the reason the restriction was added, and you should be protecting your customers instead of putting them at risk. If they're installing software, you're making them violate the OS's security and leaving gaping holes in it, and that's irresponsible of you.

And the fact that you've been using improper methodology for more than a decade doesn't speak well of your company's practices or their concern for their customers.

Loader snaps (accessible from the gflags utility which is distributed as part of the Windows SDK) is my go-to for debugging DLL load failures, along with depends.exe.  You checked the six immediate dependencies, but you didn't check their dependencies.  The default error issuance for load failures is extremely terse and tends to be misleading.

Good find Craig.  Thanks for that. In this case I found the dependencies that were offending but I will make a note that one of my threads on SO contains another more complete solution.

Have you forced the project to x86?
You can't use  "ANY CPU" since vs2022 is the FIRST version of VS that is x64 bits.
So, when you build and run, you going to have a x64 bit project when using ANY CPU. Previous versions of VS meant that ANY CPU resulted in a x32 bit default and run, since any version of vs before vs2022 was a x32 bit version.
Now that vs2022 is x64 bits, then the default ANY CPU results in your project running as x64 bits, and as such, they can't consume x32 bit dll's.
Hence, select (force) the project to run as x32 bits from here:

In addition to the above, I have to say that .dll's in the c:\windows has been locked down for years, and thus often such .dll's will be locked down, or even intercepted by virus scanning software. And to copy such files to the system folder, you will need elevated rights (hence, that location is really less then ideal for your custom dll’s).
Even projects previous to vs2022 should force the CPU settings, since unless your code and dependencies can run as x64, or x32 bits, (all .net code .dll's), then leaving this to chance and using ANY CPU means you have little idea as to what bit size your application will run as.
In your case, since those are x32 bit dll's, then you need to force your project to run as x86, and the default ANY CPU now results in an x64 bit program, not a x32 one (which was the default result when using versions of VS before vs2022.
I would move those .dll's, and also right click on them, and make sure they are un-blocked, since .net will not consume such .dll's if they been for example downloaded from the internet. In fact, even when downloading a zip file with some sample code and .dll's in that zip file? When you un-zip, the files are blocked and can't be used by .net.
So, you need to ensure that you un-block the zip file before unpacking, since any .dll's inside of that zip will also be tagged as blocked and un-safe.
So, unblock the zip file before un-zipping. Or, after un-zipping, then unblock all files and .dll's in that unzipped folder.
Hence this option:


Nice.
This doesn't seem to be the immediate issue but it has taken me in a good direction.  I'll follow up later.

Your bit sent me looking at the names of the driver support files MS is using...vs what they used to use.  (If that doesn't make your palms sweat a little...) I dropped to this as I was getting into the tall grass surrounding file security. Turns out, MS may require you to install a MSVC++ runtime environment for a ... wait for it...PREVIOUS version even if you have everything needed for the last couple versions on your current machine.  Presumably, this is seen as a lot better idea than just making the old files backward compatible.

The solution specifically was to install the C++ runtime from the 2013 version of MSVC. Works like a champ.  I'm going to eventually try to update the offending dll, however it's 3rd party and I don't want to rip anything apart until I have time to do it right/make all the necessary mistakes.
